# Twig - Automatically insert templatename as html comment

Tags: php, twig

I am working on a php project and using twig as template engine and wondering if there is a possibility to automatically add the used template filename/path into a twig template as html-comment?

That would be great for debugging, since I could have a look at the html code and find out, in which twig file I have to look, if I want to change something.

For example, the result should look like this:

```
<!-- start tpl/layout.twig -->
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <!-- start tpl/header.twig -->
    <header>My header</header>
    <!-- end tpl/layout.twig -->

    <!-- start tpl/content.twig -->
    <section>
        <!-- start tpl/article.twig -->
        <article>blabla1</article>
        <!-- end tpl/article.twig -->

        <!-- start tpl/article.twig -->
        <article>xyz</article>
        <!-- end tpl/article.twig -->
    </section>
    <!-- end tpl/content.twig -->

</body>
</html>
<!-- end tpl/layout.twig -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in your index view , you can have the name of template with :

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_template').get('name') }}
```

To get full path :

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_template')}}
```

Comment: But I would have to add this code to every template. I am looking for an automatical solution, which I can turn on/off for development/production environment.

Comment: You can create a BaseView with this code, and extended each view with it. Or, you can extend the symfony2 debug bar.