# Twig write html comment of template name used to assist debugging on large projects

Tags: twig

Is it posisble in Twig to print a comment before and after each twig template used?
[Twig - Automatically insert templatename as html comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782339/twig-automatically-insert-templatename-as-html-comment)

The above question didn't not really come up with an answer.

I have seen this functionality once in ezplatofrm, is there a handy wrapper i can call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig - display template names if debug mode is enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156570/twig-display-template-names-if-debug-mode-is-enabled)

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for thanks.

Comment: http://www.beingyesterday.com/injecting-twig-template-names-into-html-source-on-develop-environment/